# Convert value in dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hello guys i have this code, which converts a list to a 3x3 Matrix. It does some calculations, based on row and column and stores them in a dictionary.

```
def calculate(liste):
    
  calculations = {}

  matrix = np.reshape(liste,(3,3))

  keys = ['mean','variance','standard deviation', 'max','min','sum']
  operator = [np.mean, np.var, np.std, np.max, np.min, np.sum]
  
  for i in range(len(keys)):
      calculations[keys[i]] = [operator[i](matrix, axis=0),operator[i](matrix,axis=1),operator[i](liste)]
  

  return calculations

print(calculate(liste))
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'mean': [array([3., 4., 5.]), array([1., 4., 7.]), 4.0], 'variance': [array([6., 6., 6.]), array([0.66666667, 0.66666667, 0.66666667]), 6.666666666666667], 'standard deviation': [array([2.44948974, 2.44948974, 2.44948974]), array([0.81649658, 0.81649658, 0.81649658]), 2.581988897471611], 'max': [array([6, 7, 8]), array([2, 5, 8]), 8], 'min': [array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 6]), 0], 'sum': [array([ 9, 12, 15]), array([ 3, 12, 21]), 36]}
```

I would like to get rid off "array" before each array and would also like to print to the next row, when the next calculation starts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi you can add `.tolist()` in operator matrix values for example [(np.mean).tolist(), ..].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to typecast the array into a new type if you don't want it in array form.

You can change your assignment line to something like:

```
calculations[keys[i]] = [tuple(operator[i](matrix, axis=0)),tuple(operator[i](matrix,axis=1)),operator[i](liste)]
```

You can also typecast it to list(), or something else if you prefer.

For the print display, you can change it up to be something like:

```
j = calculate(liste)
for key, values in j.items():
    print(f'{key} - {values}')
```

Comment: `tolist` method is a faster way of getting a list from an array.